# Is there a standard way to organize audio tracks?

Tags: editing, recommendations, sound-editing

Usually, I order my audio tracks like this:

1. Dialogs
2. FX
3. BG
4. Music

How do you do it? Is there some kind of standard to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No "standards" that I'm aware of, but what I've seen most often in film post-production is:

1. Production
2. Dialog
3. ADR
4. Group

   ---
5. FX
6. Design
7. BG
8. Foley

   ---
9. Music

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain me what "Production", "ADR", and "Group" means?

Comment: @PedroCdB, "Production" is production dialog, or the dialog that is recorded on set. "ADR" is automated dialog replacement (also called "loops"); this is dialog that is recorded in a studio during post-production to replace production lines that are too noisy to use or need to be changed for content or better performance. Lastly, "Group" is what is usually referred to as "loop group"; again, recorded in a studio during post-production, this is where groups of voice actors gather to re-create crowd "walla" for both interior and exterior scenes.

Comment: That's a very nice explanation, thanks a lot. I am not a sound editor, so this is all "new" to me. So, the "Dialog" channel is for dialog recorded on set, but off camera, is this right?

Comment: On and off camera… Any dialogue that is recorded on set is referred to as production dialogue.

Comment: So, what about the dialog channel? If "Production" is recorded on set and ADR is recorded on studio, what is there left?